# Playback.Encrypt how to decrypt C# CodedUI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests, password-encryption

I use the following code to encrypt a password in CodedUI C#:

```
string password = Playback.Encrypt("PLAINTEXT_PASSWORD");
```

How can I decrypt it for later use in my code? I did not find a method Playback.Decrypt() :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there's a public existing method to do that, although you could certainly write one if you reverse engineer the algorithm used to encrypt it.

The obvious way if you need the password would be to just keep the plain text too since you have access to it at the point where you call `Password.Encrypt()`. Keeping it encrypted with a known key and the plain text just a method call away does not add much to security.